# what happens if I assign "reference to vector" to "vector"

Tags: c++

Friends
I happened to mistakenly write this piece of code:

```
const std::vector<int> &FunctionReturnReferenceToVector();

vector<int> tmp;
/*do something else*/
tmp = FunctionReturnReferenceToVector();
```

The compiler didn't complain, and my program ends successfully with correct result.

May I ask what exactly happened during the whole process?

I used CLion IDE and Clang as compiler.

Comment: Why do you expect it to fail?

Comment: I just don't like implicit conversion, like assignment between inconsistent types

Comment: How would you expect to get a copy of something from a reference?

Comment: @Kevin as I said, I mistakenly did this, actually I was hoping to operate on the original vector, not the copy

Comment: Right. My question is, if you *wanted* a copy, but didn't want this syntax to work, what do you want the syntax to be? A `static_cast` or something?

Comment: I think this touches the core problem: I was thinking how the conversion direction would be, if there is a conversion. Now that you pointed it out, I think I can call this a brain fart. : ) @Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the assignment operator of `std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) (and [the copy constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) as well), you will see that *there isn't one that takes another `vector<>` by value*.

They are passed *by reference* anyway (and then copied by the copy constructor, which is why it is called *copy* constructor).

A reference is generally as good as "the real thing". As long as the vector `FunctionReturnReferenceToVector()` returns a reference to *still exists*, all is well...

It **does** still exist, does it? If it only existed locally in that function, you're in trouble. ;-)

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: Ninja'd. ;-)

Comment: Hahaha, 6 seconds after my comment. You are very quick sir.

Answer (score 1):

Your vector will be copied. `tmp` will be a copy of the vector to which the reference refers. You can see this behaviour in your own fun example. Like this:

```
struct Copy {
    Copy(int in) : _i(in) {}
    // Copy assignment, just like std::vector!
    Copy& operator=(const Copy& copy) {
         _i = copy._i;
        std::cout << "I was Copied!\n";
    }
    int _i;
};

Copy a(3), b(5), &c = b;
a = c;
```

And the output, can you guess:

> I was Copied!

[Live example](https://ideone.com/3RfFVb)

Answer (score 1):

`tmp` will become a copy of the contents of the vector returned. The fact that `FunctionReturnReferenceToVector` returns a vector is, in this situation, immaterial, because your code is invoking the copy-assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question there a reference to a vector comes from. I assume it is returned from the function:

```
const std::vector<int> &FunctionReturnReferenceToVector();
```

In this case `tmp = FunctionReturnReferenceToVector()` simply copies a vector to the variable `tmp` using the assignment operator `std::vector<int>::operator=(const std::vector<int>&)`.

To operate with an original vector you can assign a const reference to a returned vector:

```
const auto &tmp = FunctionReturnReferenceToVector();
```